# HQL make query searching by date (Java+NetBeans)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, hql

Hi all I have the following issue. I have a table of reserves in my MySQL DB, the date columns is defined DATETIME. I need to make a query using hibernate to find all reserves in one day no matter the hour, just that its the same year month and date, and I'm doing this

```
public List<Reserve> bringAllResByDate(Date date){

em = emf.createEntityManager();
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Reserve r WHERE r.date=:date ");
q.setParameter("date", date);
```

...

I really dont know how to make it compare, and bring me just those from the specified date, any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish there were a database-agnostic way of casting datetimes as dates. This is usually how I deal with your scenario.

```
Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();

from.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
to.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Reserve r WHERE r.date > :dateFrom AND r.date < :dateTo ");
q.setParameter("dateFrom", from.getTimeInMillis());
q.setParameter("dateTo", to.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Query q = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT r FROM Reserve r WHERE cast(r.date as date) = :date");
```

Note that underlying database must support ANSI `cast(... as ...)` syntax.

Comment: I am actually using Hibernate under the hood.  cast works with hibernate it looks like.  I was under the impression that we cannot use native sql functions.  Please shed some light on this.  I've spent the whole day avoiding using mysql native functions inside my TypedQuery.

Comment: @logixplayer It's HQL.