# How do i group by date only from date time field in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

For mysql I wrote a query like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY DATE(dateTimeField)
```

But i can't use the `DATE()` function in JPQL.
Anyone have an idea how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

If You use Hibernate under the hood you can try :

1. Create your own dialect with custom function

   ```
   public class CustomPostgresqlDialect extends PostgreSQLDialect {   
       public CustomPostgresqlDialect() {
           super();
           registerFunction("truncate_date",
           new SQLFunctionTemplate( StandardBasicTypes.TIMESTAMP, "DATE(?1)" ));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register Your dialect in `persistence.xml`

   ```
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="my.own.CustomPostgresqlDialect"/>
   ```
3. Use your function in JPQL.

   ```
   select p from Post p group by truncate_date(p.dateCreated)
   ```

Comment: If using criteria builder, the following worked for me: `cb.function("truncate_date", Date.class, fromTable.get("dateCreated"));`

Answer (score 3):

For Hibernate:

**Suggestion 1:**

Use `cast(dateTimeField as date)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949588/hql-make-query-searching-by-date-javanetbeans).

**Suggestion 2:**

You can try to concatenate `year`, `month` and `year` [HQL expressions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

Take a look at line 360 of [this testcase](http://kickjava.com/src/org/hibernate/test/hql/ASTParserLoadingTest.java.htm).

```
str(year(current_date))||'-'||str(month(current_date))||'-'||str(day(current_date))
```

But take the time to see the generated SQL, it may (and probably will be) ugly and slow.

Comment: EclipseLink also supports CAST, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EclipseLink you can use the `FUNC()` function in JPQL to call a specific database function:

> **[Support for Native Database Functions Using FUNC](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Support_for_Native_Database_Functions)**

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's beyond the scope of what JPQL offers. You will have to resort to native queries.

Here's the List of available functions in JPQL:

> [Java EE Tutorial 6 > Persistence > JPQL > Functional Expressions](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html#bnbvo)