# Query JPA with formatted date

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I'm trying to implement a graph based on clients' ages and system registration.
I have written the code in SQL and it works:

```
SELECT 
    [birthdate],
    convert(date,creationDate)
FROM 
    [SELENIUM_TEST_DB].[dbo].[Client]
GROUP BY
    birthdate, convert(date,creationDate)
```

How can I write the same query in JPA?

This is what I have done but it is not working:

```
public List<?> getDateForAgeGraph(){
    Query q = em.createQuery("Select c.birthdate, convert(date,c.creationDate) From Client c group by c.birthdate ,convert(date,c.creationDate)");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

**Result:**

> No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode
>   -[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
>   +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'convert' {originalText=convert}
>   -[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
>   +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'date' {originalText=date}
>   -[DOT] DotNode: 'client0_.creationDate' {propertyName=creationDate,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=creationDate,path=c.creationDate,tableAlias=client0_,className=ge.shemo.model.client.Client,classAlias=c}
>   +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'client0_.clientID' {alias=c, className=ge.shemo.model.client.Client, tableAlias=client0_}
>   -[IDENT] IdentNode: 'creationDate' {originalText=creationDate}

Comment: Updated the question. but what I guess I have totally incorrect Query expression for JPA

Comment: Have you even read my question? I'm asking how to implement same query like in SQL Server not is there any function like convert in JPA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i group by date only from date time field in JPQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483176/how-do-i-group-by-date-only-from-date-time-field-in-jpql)

Comment: Since you are not loading any entities in your query, you might as well use a native query?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need convert because JPA handles all the data conversion for you.
What is the database type of creationDate and what type is it in your Client Entity?