# Group by date - jpa2 - postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data, jpa-2.0

I'm struggling to find a proper example to group by date instead of date time in a jpql. Note that I am connecting to a postgres db.

Query looks as follows:

```
@Query("select new example.model.ExampleModel(te.dateCreated, te.transactionStatus, sum(te.amount), count(te)) from ExampleEntity te group by te.dateCreated, te.transactionStatus")
fun findAggregatedExamples(): List<ExampleModel>
```

I need to convert the contructor arg to date and the group by to date.

Comment: Please can you look as the answer which cast in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949588/hql-make-query-searching-by-date-javanetbeans  ->  cast(... as ...)

Comment: Hi, indeed the cast as worked a treat for me. I will add working solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find something useful in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483176/how-do-i-group-by-date-only-from-date-time-field-in-jpql?rq=1)

Working Code:

```
@Query("select new example.model.ExampleModel(cast(te.dateCreated as date), te.transactionStatus, sum(te.amount), count(te)) from ExampleEntity te group by cast(te.dateCreated as date), te.transactionStatus")
fun findAggregatedExamples(): List<ExampleModel>
```

Constructor arg0 had to be changed from LocalDateTime to java.util.Date.